# sql pivot with oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following table

```
    ID    p_name     p_value
   ----   ------     --------------
    1      name       index.htm
    1      path       c:\web\site1
    1      size       400
    1      date       2011-03-12
    1      note       'test site'
    2      name       login.htm
    2      path       c:\web\site1
    2      size       500
    ...    ...        ...
    ...    ...        ...
```

I need to make it look like this

```
    ID   Name         Path
   ---   ----------   -------------
    1     index.htm    c:\web\site1
    2     login.htm    c:\web\site1
    ...   ...          ...
```

I was reading few other posts, but I could not figure out how to apply it on my example!
I just need mainly the "Name" and the "Path" and I may add others when needed!

Comment: What Version of Oracle? 10g, 11 etc?

Comment: does it make any diffrence? something general work on both?

Comment: Case works on both, 11g I believe has a pivot and unpivot function analytic; not sure if its in 10g or before though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to case it out since it seems you have a finite number of p_names for a given ID.

Attempt 2 - revised

```
Select ID, T1.P_Name as Name, T2.P_value as Path
FROM YourTableName T1
INNER JOIN yourTableName T2 
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
  and T1.P_Name = 'name' 
  and T2.P_name = 'path'
```

Attempt 1 - Blunder

```
SELECT Id,
CASE p_name when 'name' THEN P_value end as Name,
CASE p_name when 'path' THEN p_value end as Path
FROM yourTableNameHere
```

Comment: This is nice, but I get allot dublicated IDs with many NULLs on Name and Path, I'm trying to apply "group by" but no luck yet

Comment: case would have worked had we maxed out each value and grouped by ID  Just depends on which performs better and is easier to develop/read/scale.  Scaling is why I started with case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, t1.p_value name, t2.p_value path
  from mytable t1, mytable t2
 where t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.p_name = 'name'
   and t2.p_name = 'path'
```